# Add this styling

Tags: html, css, joomla, addthis, add-this-event

I have added `addthis` to a Joomla site. By default it loaded like this:

```html
<div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox"></div>
<script src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-xxx"></script>
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

I have enabled JCH (to improve speed), but `addthis` is not working. I have to keep JCH. I manage to make it work, using following code:

```html
<div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_64x64_style" data-title="title">
    <a class="addthis_button_facebook at-icon-wrapper at-share-btn at-svc-facebook" style="cursor:pointer"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_twitter" style="cursor:pointer"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" style="cursor:pointer"></a>
</div>
<!-- Go to www.addthis.com/dashboard to customize your tools -->
<script src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-xxx"></script>
```

As you see I have added the tags with the icons, in that way they load, but the styling is totally different, how can I keep same design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is here: https://www.addthis.com/academy/customizing-the-addthis-toolbox/.

In my div I had the class "addthis_sharing_toolbox" but I had to use "addthis_sharing_toolbox"

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_64x64_style">
    <a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_google_plusone"></a>
</div>
```